# how to fix bug in gitlab clone?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, gitlab, clone

I am trying to clone a repository from gitlab using IntelliJ IDEA, the repository that I mention has two branches, when I try to clone the branch using SSH or HTTPS, it does not generate any error, but when looking at the folders generated in IntelliJ the project appears empty. I already generated the key to connect via SSH.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible that the default branch just happens to be empty? Did you try switching to another branch?

Comment: Can you please provide the commands that you are running. There are two possibilities: the default branch is empty and the second is you are just fetching the repository and currently are not on any branch.

Comment: @JoachimSauer The repository currently has two branches, the main branch which is default and protected, and the develop branch, develop is the branch I am trying to clone to, the develop branch is not empty, and the main branch only has a readme.

Comment: @AshishRawat The repository currently has two branches, the main branch which is default and protected, and the develop branch, develop is the branch I am trying to clone to, the develop branch is not empty, and the main branch only has a readme.

Comment: what shows up if you run `git branch -a` in the repo? Add that to the question, please.

Comment: Does IDE prompt you to open a cloned project in a new/current window once clone has finished?
Could you please confirm whether URL that you are using has format like:
https://gitlab.com/<user>/<repository>.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I already generated the key to connect via SSH.

The you would need to use a `git@github.com:xxx` SSH URL, instead of the HTTPS URL shown in the screenshot.

Try and clone it in command-line first, without using IntelliJ IDEA and see if you see files then:

```
git clone -b develop git@github.com:<me>/<arepo>
cd arepo
```

Comment: It worked that way, now if I can see the files, what problem could I have in IntelliJ?  Thank you so much

Comment: @Jhon "what problem could I have in IntelliJ": using an HTTPS URL instead of an SSH one.